# Demographic data for Belgium or the Netherlands

Tags: data-request, europe

Where can I find population data that I can link to zip codes for BE or NL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that population for postal and political regions are not often provided in the same public dataset.

---

An option for **Belgium**:

1. 2013 population data from the government site - [LINK](http://economie.fgov.be/fr/modules/publications/statistiques/population/population_-_chiffres_population_2010_-_2012.jsp) (see right side of page)

   - Excel file for "population by commune" - [LINK](http://economie.fgov.be/fr/binaries/pop2010-2013mov_fr_tcm326-234223.xls)
   - unfortunately, uses "code INS" and not "postal code"
2. can join population data with postal data from BE post office, on commune name - [LINK](http://www.bpost.be/site/fr/residential/customerservice/search/postal_codes.html) (see Excel links on right side of page)

   - Excel download, sorted by postal code - [LINK](http://www.bpost2.be/zipcodes/files/zipcodes_num_fr.xls)

---

*(It's just a bunch of Googling. If it's useful, I can do the same for the Netherlands.)*

Comment: Thanks, I also found the [relation between INS/NIS codes and zip codes](http://www.notrebelgique.be/fr/index.php?nv=38&PHPSESSID=9a5f71191b7ef93aebab9c4276639caa)

Answer (score 3):

For the Netherlands:

This data exists at zipcode and neighbourhood level, both provided by the Central Bureau of Statistics (CBS).

##### Zipcode

The CBS publishes data per zipcode (called postalcodes in NL) on the ['kerncijfers per postcode' page](https://www.cbs.nl/nl-nl/dossier/nederland-regionaal/geografische-data/gegevens-per-postcode).

##### Neighbourhood

The CBS publishes this data in their ['wijk- en buurtstatistieken'](https://www.cbs.nl/nl-nl/dossier/nederland-regionaal/wijk-en-buurtstatistieken):

- [Data from 2004 to 2022](https://www.cbs.nl/nl-nl/reeksen/kerncijfers-wijken-en-buurten) (no English translation)
- [Data from 1995 to 2003](https://www.cbs.nl/nl-nl/dossier/nederland-regionaal/wijk-en-buurtstatistieken/kerncijfers-wijken-en-buurten-1995-2003) (no English translation)

You can also retrieve many of their other datasets through a python API:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cbsodata
The introduction to the data portal can be found here: https://www.cbs.nl/en-gb/our-services/open-data